# GLib-GObject-CRITICAL ... assertion 'quark > 0' failed

Tags: c++, gtk3, glib, gtkmm

I'm fairly new to Gtk programming. I'm using the Gtkmm library to write a simple GUI for my application.

The GUI is part of a larger application, which actually compiles to two separate executables, however I don't believe this is relevant since this question only concerns one of the two executables.

Anyway, I have the following code in client.cpp:

```
#include "client.hpp"

int main() {
    auto builder = Gtk::Builder::create();
}
```

And in client.hpp I'm simply including iostream, glibmm.h, and various gtkmm widget headers, as well as gtkmm/builder.h.

My makefile is a mess, but here it is:

```
CXXFLAGS= -std=c++14 -g
LDFLAGS=-lgmp -pthread $(shell pkg-config -libs gtkmm-3.0)
SERVER_EXE=server
CLIENT_EXE=client
CXX=g++
DIST_DIR=.
BUILD_DIR=./build

SERVER_CXXFLAGS=
CLIENT_CXXFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config --cflags gtkmm-3.0)

INCLUDE_DIRS=./include
INCLUDE_PARAMS=$(foreach d, $(INCLUDE_DIRS), -I$d)

SERVER_OBJECTS=rsa.o server_entry.o server.o
SERVER_OBJECT_PATHS=$(foreach o, $(SERVER_OBJECTS), $(BUILD_DIR)/$o)

CLIENT_OBJECTS=resources.o client.o
CLIENT_OBJECT_PATHS=$(foreach o, $(CLIENT_OBJECTS), $(BUILD_DIR)/$o)

all: $(SERVER_OBJECT_PATHS) $(CLIENT_OBJECT_PATHS)
    mkdir -p $(DIST_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CLIENT_OBJECT_PATHS) -o $(DIST_DIR)/$(CLIENT_EXE) $(LDFLAGS)
    $(CXX) $(SERVER_OBJECT_PATHS) -o $(DIST_DIR)/$(SERVER_EXE) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
    rm $(DIST_DIR)/$(CLIENT_EXE) $(DIST_DIR)/$(SERVER_EXE)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CXX) -c $< $(INCLUDE_PARAMS) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(SERVER_CXXFLAGS) $(CLIENT_CXXFLAGS)

resources.cpp:
    glib-compile-resources --target=resources.cpp --generate-source windows.gresource.xml
```

I realise that's a lot to take in, since it's actually building two executables, but for this question you can safely only regard things which are related to the *client* program.

The rule right at the bottom is used to turn the glade file I made into a c++ file which can be linked to my client.cpp file.

Anyway, when I run my program I get the following output:

```
(process:16593): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 23:15:27.886: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed
```

I'm at a complete loss as to what this error message could mean. Since I'm not very experienced with this library, I'm not sure quite what to make of it. I also tried adding a line after my code to load the builder widgets from a resource, but that created even more critical errors and segfaulted. I'm hoping if I can fix this first error, everything else will fall into place. Any thoughts? Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**: When I change the source of client.cpp to the source code supplied [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en), it works perfectly! So that's odd..

Comment: Run your program under `gdb` with `G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings` set in the environment and look at the backtrace (or post it here). See https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-running.html#G-DEBUG:CAPS

Comment: @PhilipWithnall thank you for the response. Am I right in thinking that to do this I type `G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings` and then `gdb client`, then when gdb is running I type 'run' and then 'where'? Because when I do that it just says No stack.

Comment: Yes, type them all in one command (`G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings gdb ./client`) or use `export G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings` first, then `gdb ./client`). You’ll need debug symbols installed for GLib, and your application to be compiled with `-g -O1`, in order to get a backtrace.

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure GLibMM must be initialized with `Glib::init()` before you call any Glib/Gtk functions. `Gtk::Application::create()` will do that for you, that's why the example just works.

Comment: Notice that there is a slight typo, create is lowercase: `Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv);`