# Why does gtk_recent_manager_add_full () silently fail?

Tags: c, gtk3

### The main goal

I wrote a python simple program that adds a file to the recent files list in GTK3. It gets called when vim opens a file. It's working fine, but vim's startup time is multiplied by 10. Now I'm trying to port it to C so as to improve this flaw. Here is a demo of the python script I'm trying to port :

```py
from gi import require_version
require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

manager = Gtk.RecentManager()
recent_data = Gtk.RecentData()

recent_data.app_name = "vim"
recent_data.mime_type = "text/plain"
recent_data.app_exec = "/usr/bin/vim"
manager.add_full("file:///home/lafleur/tweaks.txt", recent_data)
```

### What I attempted

See the code sample below. It compiles fine, but I get a CRITICAL warning when I run it, and then the process succeeds, but the file doesn't show up in the recent files in Nautilus.

Here is the traceback :

```sh
$ ./a.out
adding file:///home/lafleur/tweaks.txt to recent files

(process:17646): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:37:32.034: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
file added to recent files.
```

I'm unable to tell what went wrong. I followed docs in [GNOME's GTK3 documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRecentManager.html). Those docs state that the mandatory arguments to `gtk_recent_manager_add_full ()` are the gtk_recent_manager, a uri and a `GtkRecentData` object holding the file's MIME type, the application name and its callback. When compiled, the process complains that it needs an application description, which I added in the sample (see below). I found `g_object_get ()`'s definition [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-get), but that doesn't give me any clue.

### The question

My question is : how can I know what's happening and why the process fails to add the existing `/home/lafleur/tweaks.txt` to Nautilus' recent files listing ? How can I know what in my code is not a valid GObject ? Did I miss some initialization, as stated in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53936917/11305897) ?

Here is the code sample :

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkRecentData recent_data;
  GtkRecentManager *manager;
  GError *error = NULL;
  gchar *uri;
  gboolean retval;

  uri = g_filename_to_uri ("/home/lafleur/tweaks.txt", NULL, &error);
  manager = gtk_recent_manager_get_default ();
  if (error) {
      g_warning ("%s", error->message);
      g_error_free (error);
  } else {
    recent_data.mime_type = "text/plain";
    recent_data.app_name = "vim";
    recent_data.app_exec = "/usr/bin/vim";
    recent_data.description = "the vim editor";
    g_print ("adding %s to recent files\n", uri);
    retval = gtk_recent_manager_add_full (
        manager,
        uri,
        &recent_data
    );
    if (retval == TRUE) {
      g_print ("file added to recent files.\n");
    } else {
      g_warning ("there was a problem.\n");
    }
    g_free (uri);
  }
  return retval;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using GTK API from C, you need to initialize GTK itself, with something like:

```c
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
```

where `argc` and `argv` are pointers to the arguments counter and vector that you get in your `main`. If you don't do this, anything that follows is undefined behaviour.

The Python bindings, for reasons of backward compatibility in the days of GTK 1 and 2, call `gtk_init()` automatically when imported.

Additionally, `GtkRecentManager` queues updates within the GTK main loop, to coalesce multiple writes into one; this is not normally an issue in GUI applications, but if you're writing a CLI tool, you will need to also spin the main loop until the `GtkRecentManager` emits the "changed" signal.

Your program will work once you modify it to call `gtk_init()` first, and then spin the main loop until the write is done, e.g.:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GError *error = NULL;
  char *uri = g_filename_to_uri ("/home/lafleur/tweaks.txt", NULL, &error);

  // Bail out early in case of error
  if (error != NULL) {
      g_warning ("%s", error->message);
      g_error_free (error);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // You can pass (NULL, NULL) if you don't have arguments; if you
  // want to deal with the possibility of not having a display
  // connection, you can use gtk_init_check() instead.
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  // Create the recent manager
  GtkRecentManager *manager = gtk_recent_manager_get_default ();

  // Create a main loop; the recent manager will schedule writes
  // within the loop, so it can coalesce multiple operations.
  GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  // Once we receive the "changed" signal from the recent manager
  // we stop the main loop; we use the "swapped" variant so that
  // the callback will be invoked with the signal's user data
  // as the first argument; in this case, we're going to call
  // g_main_loop_quit() on the loop object
  g_signal_connect_swapped (manager, "changed",
                            G_CALLBACK (g_main_loop_quit),
                            loop);

  GtkRecentData recent_data = {
    .mime_type = "text/plain",
    .app_name = "vim",

    // The "app_exec" key should be the command line needed to open
    // the file you're adding; the %f escape sequence means "use the
    // path of the file", whereas the %U escape sequence means "use
    // the URL of the file".
    .app_exec = "/usr/bin/vim %f",
    .description = "the vim editor",
  };

  g_print ("adding %s to recent files\n", uri);

  gboolean retval = gtk_recent_manager_add_full (
    manager,
    uri,
    &recent_data
  );

  // Never compare boolean values for equality; gboolean is an int-sized
  // type, which means anything that is not FALSE/0 will have a TRUE value
  if (retval) {
    g_print ("file added to recent files.\n");
  } else {
    g_warning ("there was a problem.\n");
  }

  g_free (uri);

  // Start the loop; this will block until GtkRecentManager emits the
  // "changed" signal, telling us the the recently used files list has
  // been updated
  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  // Use standard exit codes
  return retval ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Since you must call `gtk_init()`, you **will** need a connection to your display server; this means you cannot run this program under a pure virtual terminal outside of your graphical session. If you need to do that, you will need to write your own "recent manager", using the [`GBookmarkFile`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Bookmark-file-parser.html) API, which is the same API GTK uses internally. The `GBookmarkFile` API is definitely more low level, though, and it requires you understand the file format and location used for the recently used files.

Comment: Beautiful answer, thank you very much ! But ... I still wonder _where_ I could have found all those precious hints you give (e.g. using `gtk_init ()`). Besides, while it does compile and run successfully, the file still doesn't appear in Nautilus' recent files. Would you have a clue ?

Comment: And last, do we have to `#include <stdlib.h>` ? The code compiles and runs successfully without it (same behaviour as without it).

Comment: You need to read the GTK API reference if you want to know more about using GTK; the requirement of calling `gtk_init()` is part of the page on the main loop and initialisation: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html — though we are trying to improve it. The `stdlib.h` include is needed for `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`. I just noticed that I missed spinning the main loop, so the write won't happen; I'll amend the example.